# Access remote server with private IP through a *DIFFERENT* server with public IP

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Let's assume the following hosts:

```
localhost : my laptop 
remoteserver : a server with a public IP which runs a SSH server on port 22. (remoteserver ip for example 194.152.16.111) 
private.remoteserver ssh on port 2255: a server with a private IP which is only accessible from remoteserver. (private.remoteserver ip for example 194.152.16.222
```

)

I want to create ssh tunnel that I can connect to private.remoteserver from my laptop threw remoteserver

I tryed this

```
ssh -L 2255:194.152.16.222:2255 admin@194.152.16.111

and then from laptop

ssh localhost:2255
```

but does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to do what is called "multi hop ssh" and connect from host A via host B to host C is with the `ProxyJump` command switch `-J` available in newer ssh versions:

```
 ssh -J userB@hostB:portB userC@hostC:portC
```

where the port numbers are only needed when a port number different from the default ssh port 22, is used.

Or with scp

```
 scp -o 'ProxyJump userB@hostB' localfile userC@hostC:/remote/path/
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error now:

channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: To debug add one or more `-v` flags and check the server logs first on hostB and then on hostC  for possible causes of your error message. - What I suggested may be impossible when the intermediate server hostB is configured with for  instance [`PermitOpen none`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitOpen)

Comment: Thank you. Looks like that i can not specify port 2255

debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd xxx:2255:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Comment: I add -p now for port but does not ask me for password ....

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host <internal.ips>
    Proxycommand ssh -C -W %h:%p -q -A <public server ip>
```

just make sure internal.ips are accessible from the public server.